# Make instance of view controller and segue to it programatically

Tags: ios, swift, segue, presentviewcontroller

I have two view controllers in my storyboard: `view1` and `view2`.

In `view1`, I used the storyboard to make a segue from its tableview to `view2`.

But now in `view2`, I have programmatically created a button, and it is supposed to segue to another instantiated `view2`.

When the button is clicked, I made a function to execute:

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton){
  //TODO:- GET NEXT PAGE
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("anotherView2", sender: sender)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if(segue.identifier == "anotherView2"){
    let anotherView2Controller = segue.destinationViewController as! View2
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Of course it does not work, since there is no segue identifier called `anotherView2`. So I want to make it somehow, but I really cannot find good way to manage this.

Is there anyway to create the segue programmatically? I tried to make the segue from storyboard, but since the button is created programatically, I cannot segue to `view2` to `view2`.

Comment: I think you need to look into the difference between a view and a view controller.

Comment: Oh my bad. view1 and view 2 are both view controller.

Comment: Have you tried using presentViewController instead of performSegue?

Comment: No. What does that do? I have to send one parameter to the new view2, so I was trying to use prepareForSegue. Sorry, I am not super specialist with Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `presentViewController` instead of `performSegue`:

```
// however you want to initialize the new vc
let vc2 : View2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2.id") as! View2
```

an alternate way to init the vc is to do this:

```
let vc2 = View2()
```

and then set the data and present:

```
vc2.index = index // whatever you want to pass
self.presentViewController(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Otherwise you could create a new view controller in your storyboard, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: But does it perform segue eventually? I have to go through the prepareForSegue before segue takes place.

Comment: No it doesn't and you don't have to. You can just pass the data before you present. I'd suggest reading my answer.

Comment: If I replace my "buttonPressed" function with your code, I get error saying:

Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7a7f6350>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'view2.id''

I am really sorry but I am lost with your answer. I never managed storyboard programatically before, and I think that is why I cannot understand your answer

Comment: Yeah, as expected, because you have to add the identifier to your storyboard

Comment: Or you know, you could have read the comment and initialized your view controller however you wanted, not just the way I had done it.

Comment: I read your comment, but maybe I am not understanding correctly. 
I thought 

let vc2 : View2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2.id") as! View2

add the identifier as view2.id. So I dont understand I get the error

Comment: You have to add the identifier to the view controller in the story board. If you don't understand how to do this, I'd recommend googling how to add a storyboard identifier to a view controller.

Comment: Oh shoot I got it. Thank you for so much help.

Comment: Glad to have helped!